# Is UN state and D state in Linux processes are same?

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, kdump

I want to understand is the `UN` and `D` process state is the same? During the analysis of `vmcore` (crash dump) I have found lots of `UN` state processes.

And when I googled it I hardly found any document on the `UN` state but found `D` state document.

Can someone please let me know if `UN` and `D` state is the same?

OS is Redhat 7

```
104      2   6  ffff8817ee65a400  **UN**   0.0       0      0  [sync_supers]
14678      1   9  ffff8810854d8440  **UN**   0.1  535472 157188  ohasd.bin
14803      1  20  ffff8828b6ebe5c0  **UN**   0.0  372100  34420  evmd.bin
```

Comment: I've never seen `**UN**`. My guess is that means it means "undefined", and whatever you are using to output it can't interpret the bit pattern. So either your output program is incomplete, or the internal structures are screwed up.

Comment: This is found during the crash dump analysis

Comment: Is this state is same as D state?